# Super Rails (aka using sudo with rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Whenever I try to create a new rails app I get a permission denied error. Yet when I try running rails as sudo it says rails is not a command. How would I use rails in a protected directory? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Rails binary is not in a path that sudo can see, it won't run as sudo. This happens a lot on Ubuntu systems where the sudo environment is locked down.

I have no idea why you're having this type of problem though - the 'rails' command is meant to be run during development, and you'd usually not be working in a locked-down directory. My advice is to fix whatever permission problems you're having.

If yo're trying to create a Rails application on a server you don't control, you should know that's not the way Rails developers typically work. We usually develop locally and use some tool like Caipstrano or other scripting tool to pull the code from a version control system onto the server.

Without knowing more specifics, I'm afraid I can't be any more helpful than that. But I hope this clears some things up.

Comment: Ok, I'll set up a git repository and develop it on my personal computer. Thanks.